# Three.js - fixing distorted lighting when twisting the geometry

Tags: three.js

I am working on a geometry which is basically a rod twisted around the z-axis by a specific angle. This is done by modifying the vertices of an ExtrudeGeometry based on their position along the z-direction:

```
function twistMesh(mesh, helixAngle){
    var vertices = mesh.geometry.vertices;
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        var angle = helixAngle*vertices[i].z/100;
        var updateX = vertices[i].x * Math.cos(angle)
                                    - vertices[i].y * Math.sin(angle);
        var updateY = vertices[i].y * Math.cos(angle)
                                    + vertices[i].x * Math.sin(angle);
        vertices[i].x = updateX;
        vertices[i].y = updateY;
    }
    return mesh;
}
```

[image]

A working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nlooije/pamv8krb/112/).

I am running into the problem that the lighting is not update along with the modified vertices, i.e. it seems as if the light incident on the surface is equally modified.

I have read that when modifying a update call is required by setting:

```
mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
mesh.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
```

however, this doesn't seem to fix the lighting issue i am seeing.

How do I update or otherwise 'fix' the distorted lighting when twisting my geometry this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you update the vertices, you need to update the vertex normals, too.

You can do that manually, where you will have the most control, or you can use the built-in method:

```
mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pamv8krb/144/

three.js r.95